# How to sort number output descending

Tags: sql, sorting

I have my database , it has medical insurances and people .
And the output I'm looking for is how many people are in health insurance company #1 , health insurance company #2 and so on . It also should be sorted descend .

```
hicompany: (db 1)
id,name
1,abc
2,edf
3,ghi

people: (db 2)
code,company
0001,abc
0002,edf
0003,ghi

pupil: (db 3)
code
0001
0002
0003
```

And here is my sql query:

```
SELECT k.name AS hicompany, count( * ) AS howmany
ROM people p
JOIN hicompany k ON p.id= k.id
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT k.name AS hicompany, count( * ) AS howmany
FROM people p
JOIN hicompany k ON p.id= k.id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: perfect query!   as additional if need maybe  add HAVING COUNT(*) > 4   <br>PLUS 1 from me  Goat CO

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line at the end:

```
ORDER BY howmany DESC
```